# DateTime.FromOADate returns different date from the Date in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

In an Excel cell, I put 12, if I format it as Date, then it is 1/12/1900.
In C#, I use DateTime.FromOADate(12), it returns 1/11/1900.
but if I put 411 in Excel and format it as date, it will be 2/14/1901.
In C#, DateTime.FromOADate(411) returns 2/14/1901, too. 
I am confused about the discrepancy.  How can I get the right Date in C# then?

Comment: Why don't you just provide regular formatted dates?

Comment: The issue is sometimes users put numbers in cells where require Dates, So I have to convert for them in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an Excel quirk where it emulates a Lotus 1-2-3 bug for compatibility.
The year 1900 was not a leap year, but Excel treats it as a leap year to be compatible with the Lotus 1-2-3 bug. The OLE date/time processing correctly does not.

There is this amusing anecdote about the issue: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html

If you need to work around this and emulate the Excel behaviour before 1 March 1900, you can set a double instead of a date, and do a DateTime to double conversion that respects the Excel bug too. Internally Excel always represents the dates as doubles anyway.